# Using the ClassLoader method to retrieve all resources under classes as Input Streams

Tags: java, classloader

My problem is one that you would think is quite common, but I haven't so far managed to find a solution.

Building a Java web app under Tomcat 5.5 (although a requirement is that it can be deployed anywhere, like under a WebLogic environment, hence the loading resources as streams requirement). Good practice dictates that resource files are placed under *WEB-INF/classes* and loaded using the ClassLoader's *getResourceAsStream()* method. All well and good when you know the name of the resource you want to load.

My problem is that I need to load everything (including recursively in non-empty sub-directories) that lives in a subdirectory of *classes*.

So, for example, if I have the following under *WEB-INF/classes*:

*folderX/folderY*

*folderX/folderY/fileA.properties*

*folderX/fileB.properties*

I need the fileA.properties and fileB.properties classes to be loaded, without actually knowing their names before the application is started (ie I need the ability to arbitrarily load resources from any directory under WEB-INF/classes).

What is the most elegant way to do this? What object could I interrogate to find the information I need (the resource paths to each of the required resources)? A non-servlet specific solution would be best (keeping it all within the  class loading framework if possible).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with some tricks :)

Get the resource as URL, extract the protocol :

- file protocol - get the URL path and you have a folder, scan for files.
- jar/zip protocol - extract the jar/zip path and use JarFile to browse the files and extract everything under your path/package.

Comment: Couldn't an web server return an http protocol pointing to itself? I would say at a minimum such an approach should be tested on all target web servers to make sure it works.

Comment: Sun Jersey REST implementation uses this approach to search for specific classes based on package name(looking for classes with a specific annotation).

Comment: What about WebLogic's limitations in terms of the unexploded WAR deployment? Wouldn't any attempt to instantiate and interrogate File objects cause problems under WebLogic?

Comment: No, absolute not. Playing with File or ZipFile objects doesn't effect the container, no matter which one do you use.

Comment: The file protocol may work. Extracting the jar/zip would include your entire application .war and/or .ear archives recursively. This seems like more than just tricky! If someone figures it out robustly then they should make a nice open source project!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, there is no such ability, since the classloader only attempts to load things it is asked for. It doesn't pre-fetch all items on the classpath, or treat them as a directory structure.

The way I would solve the problem is create a directory listing in a text file of all relevant resources at build time and include that in the war, and then walk it through that way.